# External audio inputs using MediaDevices.getUserMedia in mobile devices

Tags: audio, mobile, microphone, getusermedia

I am developing a mobile app and web for video and audio production. I am using mediadevices enumerateDevices and getusermedia methods to get audio from audio inputs. On laptop and desktop everything works fine. In smartphones, it works great with built-in microphones. When I try with external microphones (like behringer USB or shure Mv88), the device appears on the list (enumerateDevices), we can select it but then the audio capture always uses the built-in microphone. What can be the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
        try {
          let constraints: any = {
            video: false,
            audio: {
              deviceId: this.publishSettings.audioDevice.deviceId,
              echoCancellation: true
            }
          }
          this.audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
          if (this.audioStream.getAudioTracks().length > 0){
            this.audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = !this.isMuted;
          }
          this.audioStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            let l_Settings: MediaTrackSettings = track.getSettings();
            console.log("[PublishStreamComponent] (openMedia) Audio Stream Settings: " + l_Settings.deviceId + " " + track.kind + " echoCancel "  + l_Settings.echoCancellation);
          })
          l_Ret = true;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("[PublishStreamComponent] : openMedia Audio Error " + error);
          l_Ret = false;
        }
```

Comment: Different makes (iOS, Android) and versions of smartphones work differently. Which ones do you use?

Comment: I am testing in both platforms. On iOS I have not been able to make it work trying with iPhone XR, iPhone11, iPhone12. Same with Android, it does not work. It always gets the built-in microphone. There is a "miracle" exception with a Samsung S20. In this smartphone the external audio devices work fine with getUserMedia.